# Getting security credentials from ec2 role is not allowing java client access

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-iam

I've launched an ec2 instance with a role.  The role has the following policy

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
{
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Action": "*",
  "Resource": "*"
}]}
```

and the role is trusted by ec2.amazonaws.com

On the instance I'm then getting the access key and secret key from a java program by calling

```
curl http://169.254.169.254/2012-01-12/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/myrole/
```

I'm then trying to use those credentials to make sns requests.

I'm getting

```
<ErrorResponse xmlns="http://sns.amazonaws.com/doc/2010-03-31/">
  <Error>
     <Type>Sender</Type>
     <Code>InvalidClientTokenId</Code>
      <Message>The security token included in the request is invalid</Message>
```

When I hardcode the credentials with my own keys, the request goes through as expected.

Comment: can we see the request? (mask the sensitive info that you must)

Comment: I think the issue is with the older API that we are using (2010-03-31).  I'm testing the aws demo app now http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSdkDocsJava/latest/DeveloperGuide/java-dg-roles.html

Answer (score 2):

Solved this by using the AWS SDK.  The SDK does credential lookup from the role automatically.  Alternatively, I could of continued using the old API, if I did an AssumeRole Call

From a faqs page in the documentation that explained it

> Q: How do I assume an IAM role?
>   You assume an IAM role by calling the AWS Security Token Service (STS) AssumeRole APIs (i.e., AssumeRole, AssumeRoleWithWebIdentity, and AssumeRoleWithSAML). These APIs return a set of temporary security credentials that applications can then use to sign requests to AWS service APIs.

Comment: Glad you resolved it.  This is one key advantage of using the AWS SDKs (Java, Python, and others) on instances with assigned IAM roles - there's no need to have explicit credentials on the instance or supply them to the connection APIs.  It all happens under the covers.